# Problemas para filtrar conteúdo de tabelas usando <select>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tenho um select com os gêneros "Masculino" e "Feminino", ao selecionar um desses gêneros, é mostrado outro select com modalidades de esportes e cada uma dessas modalidades imprime uma tabela.

Sou iniciante em jQuery e preciso que as tabelas sejam filtradas de acordo com a opção selecionada do select.

Por exemplo, se eu selecionei o gênero "Feminino" ele mostraria o segundo select com as modalidades, selecionando então uma das modalidades ele mostraria a sua respectiva tabela abaixo. Trocando a modalidade a tabela também seria trocada, caso o gênero seja alterado, gostaria que retornasse para a tabela em branco com o select das modalidades.

Quando eu seleciono outra modalidade, a tabela anterior não desaparece. Como eu poderia resolver tal problema?

Segue o código que estou usando:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#top-escolas-genero').change(function() {
    var marca = $('#top-escolas-genero').val();
    switch (marca) {
      case 'blank-table':
        $('#blank-table').show();
        $('#table-atletismo-masculino, #table-atletismo-feminino, #table-basquete-masculino, #table-basquete-feminino, #top-escolas-modalidade-masculino, #top-escolas-modalidade-feminino').hide();
        break;
      case 'top-escolas-modalidade-masculino':
        $('#top-escolas-modalidade-masculino').show();
        $('#top-escolas-modalidade-feminino').hide();
        break;
      case 'top-escolas-modalidade-feminino':
        $('#top-escolas-modalidade-feminino').show();
        $('#top-escolas-modalidade-masculino').hide();
        break;
            
      default:
        $('#blank-table').show();
        $('#table-atletismo-masculino, #table-atletismo-feminino, #table-basquete-masculino, #table-basquete-feminino, #top-escolas-modalidade-masculino, #top-escolas-modalidade-feminino').hide();
        break;
    }
  });
  $('#top-escolas-modalidade-masculino, #top-escolas-modalidade-feminino').change(function() {
    var modelo = $(this).val();
      
    if (modelo = ('#' + this.value)){
        $('#' + this.value).show();
        $('#blank-table').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#' + this.value).hide();
        $('#blank-table').show();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="top-escolas-title">
                   <p class="font-50-40"><span>Top 10</span> Melhores Escolas</p>
               </div>
               <select name="top-escolas-modalidade-masculino" id="top-escolas-modalidade-masculino" style="display:none;" class="select-modalidades font-35-30">
                    <option selected value="blank-table">Modalidade</option>
                    <option data-section="atletismo-masculino" value="table-atletismo-masculino">Atletismo</option>
                    <option data-section="basquete-masculino" value="table-basquete-masculino">Basquete</option>
                    <option data-section="msub14" value="mSub14">Futsal</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Ginástica Artística</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Ginástica Rítmica</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Handebol</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Judô</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Natação</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Society</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Tênis de Campo</option>
                    <option data-section="msub08" value="mSub08">Tênis de Mesa</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Vôlei</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Xadrez</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Patinação</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Jogos Eletrônicos</option>
                </select>
                
                <select name="top-escolas-modalidade-feminino" id="top-escolas-modalidade-feminino" style="display:none;" class="select-modalidades font-35-30">
                    <option selected value="blank-table">Modalidade</option>
                    <option data-section="atletismo-feminino" value="table-atletismo-feminino">Atletismo</option>
                    <option data-section="basquete-feminino" value="table-basquete-feminino">Basquete</option>
                    <option data-section="msub14" value="mSub14">Futsal</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Ginástica Artística</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Ginástica Rítmica</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Handebol</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Judô</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Natação</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Society</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Tênis de Campo</option>
                    <option data-section="msub08" value="mSub08">Tênis de Mesa</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Vôlei</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Xadrez</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Patinação</option>
                    <option data-section="msub17" value="mSub17">Jogos Eletrônicos</option>
                </select>
                
                <select name="top-escolas-genero" id="top-escolas-genero" class="select-genero font-35-30">
                    <option selected class="on.click" value="">Gênero</option>
                    <option data-section="atletismo-masculino" class="on.click" value="top-escolas-modalidade-masculino">Masculino</option>
                    <option data-section="atletismo-feminino" class="on.click" value="top-escolas-modalidade-feminino">Feminino</option>
                </select>
                
                <div id="blank-table" class="end-map modalidades-table"  data-name="blank-table">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[table id=31 /]');?> teste 1
                </div>
                
                <div id="table-atletismo-masculino" class="end-map modalidades-table"  style="display:none;" data-name="atletismo-masculino">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[table id=1 /]');?> teste 3
                </div>
                
                <div id="table-atletismo-feminino" class="end-map modalidades-table"  style="display:none;" data-name="atletismo-feminino">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[table id=2 /]');?> teste 4
                </div>
                
                <div id="table-basquete-masculino" class="end-map modalidades-table" style="display:none;" data-name="basquete-masculino">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[table id=3 /]');?> teste 5
                </div>
                
                <div id="table-basquete-feminino" class="end-map modalidades-table" style="display:none;" data-name="basquete-feminino">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[table id=4 /]');?> teste 6
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Montei um exemplo usando jQuery pra você, basta ler os comentários com atenção.

```js
//Primeiro vamos definir com quem vamos mexer frequentemente:

const
   //Containers, pra fazer os selects abrir e fechar
   $masculinoContainer = $( '#modalidades-masculino-container' ),
   $femininoContainer = $( '#modalidades-feminino-container' ),
   
   //Selects, pra fazer as tabelas abrirem e fecharem
   $genero = $( '#genero' ),
   $modalidadeMasculino = $( '#modalidades-masculino' ),
   $modalidadeFeminino = $( '#modalidades-feminino' ),
   
   //Masculinos, divs onde o id CONTÉM "masculino"
   $masculinos = $( 'div[id*="masculino"]' ),
   
   //Femininos, divs onde o id CONTÉM "feminino"
   $femininos = $( 'div[id*="feminino"]' ),
   
   //Tabelas
   $tabelas = $( '.table-container' );

//Ao selecionar um genero
$genero.change( () => {
  
  //Pega o valor
  switch($genero.val()){
  
    //Caso Masculino
    case 'M':
      //Esconde o feminino  E mostra o masculino
      $femininoContainer.hide() && $masculinoContainer.show();
      break;
      
    //Caso Feminino
    case 'F':
      //Esconde o masculino E mostra o feminino
      $masculinoContainer.hide() && $femininoContainer.show();
    break;
    
    //Senão Esconde Tudo
    default:
       $masculinos.hide() && $femininos.hide() && $tabelas.hide();
    break;
  }
  
} );

//Ao selecionar uma modalidade do Masculino
$modalidadeMasculino.change( () => {
  $femininos.hide() && $tabelas.hide();
  
  //Mostra a tabela com id modalidade-genero selecionados
  $( '#' + $modalidadeMasculino.val() + '-masculino' ).show();
} );

//Ao selecionar uma modalidade do Feminino
$modalidadeFeminino.change( () => {
  $masculinos.hide() && $tabelas.hide();
  
  $( '#' + $modalidadeFeminino.val() + '-feminino' ).show();
} );
```

```css
.invisible{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- SELECTS -->
<div>
  <select id="genero">
    <option>Escolha um Gênero</option>
    <option value="M">Masculino</option>
    <option value="F">Feminino</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br />
<div class="invisible" id="modalidades-masculino-container">
  <select id="modalidades-masculino">
    <option>Escolha uma Modalidade</option>
    <option value="atletismo">Atletismo</option>
    <option value="basquete">Basquete</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br />
<div class="invisible" id="modalidades-feminino-container">
  <select id="modalidades-feminino">
    <option>Escolha uma Modalidade</option>
    <option value="atletismo">Atletismo</option>
    <option value="basquete">Basquete</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br />

<!-- TABELAS -->
<div class="invisible table-container" id="atletismo-masculino">
  <h3>atletismo-masculino</h3>
</div>
<div class="invisible table-container" id="atletismo-feminino">
  <h3>atletismo-feminino</h3>
</div>
<div class="invisible table-container" id="basquete-masculino">
  <h3>basquete-masculino</h3>
</div>
<div class="invisible table-container" id="basquete-feminino">
  <h3>basquete-feminino</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: é isso que eu preciso, só tem um problema, por exemplo, se eu estou no genero "masculino" com a tabela de "basquete" selecionada, e troco o genero pra "feminino" a tabela que estava selecionada não retorna até eu selecionar uma nova, eu precisava que quando selecionasse o genero a primeira tabela fosse sempre a em branco.

Comment: @Gouper Ai você faz assim, ali no `default` do `switch`, que é quando nenhum dos dois é escolhido, você da um `.show` na tabela em branco ; )

Comment: eu dei uma pequena editada e consegui o que precisava, muito obrigado pela ajuda!